# Cannot read property "setColumnFilterCriteria" of null

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a copy of a spreadsheet with some macros. When I tried to run the macros, I get the error below even though I did not change the script at all.

"setColumnFilterCriteria" comes up multiple times in the macro but here is the first time

```
  samsara.getRange(1,B,maxrow,87).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(1, 87);
  samsara.getRange(2,G).activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(G, criteria);var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

I thought the Filter is in the line above the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message of `Cannot read property “setColumnFilterCriteria” of null`, I thought that in your situation, there might not be the filter in the sheet. When the filter is not existing in the sheet, `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter()` returns `null`. By this, such error occurs. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(G, criteria);var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

#### To:

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var filter = sheet.getFilter();
if (filter) {
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(G, criteria);
} else {
  sheet.getRange(2, G, sheet.getLastRow()).createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(G, criteria);
}
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

- In this modification, when the filter is not existing, the filter is created as new filter. When the filter is existing, the existing filter is modified.
- In this modification, I used `sheet.getRange(2, G, sheet.getLastRow())` as the range of filter. When your actual range is different from it, please modify it.

#### References:

- [getFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getfilter)
- [createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter)